# Is this MTB a good bike or a BSO? Deserve carbon MTB

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, carbon, bso

A guy wants to sell it to me second-hand, according to him hardly used. He bought it for USD850, trying to sell it for USD 180 to me. Is it ok to buy? I'm worried because it's imported wholesale from China with no brand (never heard of Deserve brand). Also, is it suitable for a man of height 163cm? Or too big? Thanks!

Deserve Carbon Mountain Bike

[image]
Specification : 
Frame: 26"*18" Full-Carbon Fiber.
Fork: 26"SR SUNTOUR EPICON Aluminum Remote Lockout.
Chain Wheel: SHIMANO XT Aluminum 42T*32T*24T.
Chain: SHIMANO HG95.
Head set: Sealed Bearings Cartridge.
BB Set: SHIMANO XT.
Pedals: MOSSO Aluminum.
Saddle: WTB.
Handlebar: MOSSO Φ31.8 Carbon.
Stem: MOSSO Φ31.8 Carbon.
Seat Post: MOSSO Φ31.8 Carbon.
Tire: WTB 26"*2.1 Tubeless.
Wheels: WTB.
Brake: SHIMANO XT.
Derailleur: SHIMANO XT 30SP.

Comment: We don't do product rec here, but its not a BSO -- you wouldn't make a BSO out of carbon fiber. However, it does seem to be  a non-major brand chinese CF frame, and that would give me a lot of hesitation on safety and build quality. Some of the other things are weird too, such as the Epicon fork, which seems like something quite low end to attach to a  CF frame.

Comment: As to whether it fits, you have to ride it to decide that.

Comment: Its not a brand named bike, but its far from a BSO.  Full XT drive train, carbon frame, airshock, hardly used condition $180.... probably stolen.

Comment: Yep, it seems a bit too good a deal... you should ask to see the receipt of purchase.

Comment: A "full carbon fiber" suspension fork?? Does such a thing even exist?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments guys. He's selling because he migrated overseas and maybe nobody wants to buy it at a high price. It's not stolen because he showed me the chat history of the purchase.  It's "full carbon fiber" and  "Fork" separately. I'll probably buy it, just hoping it fits and the CF frame is good quality.

Comment: As I said earlier, I think you should really consider that the CF frame is good quality. Its not something you can test just by looking at it, and CF generally fails quite catastrophically, so you're putting a **lot** of trust into the quality (and even for big brands, there are a ton of fakes sold now, so buying from a reputable dealer is essential).

Comment: Chat history is pretty easy to fake.

Comment: hence the $180 price tag maybe. At that price, If I knew it was not stolen, I would buy it for the parts and get a donor frame. Certainly the I would chuck the stem and bars and replace with something I trusted. Frame I would probably keep.

Comment: Thanks again for the comments. Now I am worried about the CF frame quality. I think I might look for other non-carbon second-hand bikes instead.

Comment: maybe it's just stolen **and** "rebranded" by painting